# Field 'Id_employeer' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I don't understand why my app drop Exception "Field 'Id_employeer' doesn't have a default value".

`Id_employeer` is my primary key, when I try to save any information to my database I got that exception, but, when I try just to read info from DB it's working.

I read topic on StackOverflow, but I still don't understand the answers in my app. I'm working with Hibernate 5.2.11.

My `CharacterInfo.hbm.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="CharacterInfo" table="employees">
        <id name="Id" column="id_employeer">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Login" column="employeer_login"/>



    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

My HibernateUtility:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import java.util.List;


public class HibernateUtility {


    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void saving(Object object){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save( object);
        //session.save( new CharacterInfo().getLogin());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void reading(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery("from CharacterInfo").list();
        for ( CharacterInfo characterInfo : (List<CharacterInfo>) result ) {
            System.out.println( "CharacterInfo (" + characterInfo.getLogin() + ") : " + characterInfo.getLogin() );
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }


    protected void setUp() throws Exception {

        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure()
                .build();

        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }




}
```

Next CharacterInfo class

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table( name = "employees")
public class CharacterInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "Id_employeer")
    private int id ;

    @Column(name = "employeer_Login")
    private String login;


    public CharacterInfo() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }



}
```

main class

```
public class main {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        HibernateUtility hibernateUtility = new HibernateUtility();
        CharacterInfo characterInfo = new CharacterInfo();
        characterInfo.setId(1);
        characterInfo.setLogin("PawJaw");
        hibernateUtility.setUp();
        hibernateUtility.saving(characterInfo);


    }
}
```

and in the end Exception

> ERROR: Field 'Id_employeer' doesn't have a default value Exception in
>   thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2919)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3490)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:626)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:280)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:306)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:691)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:683)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:678)     at
>   HibernateUtility.saving(HibernateUtility.java:17)     at
>   main.main(main.java:10) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field
>   'Id_employeer' doesn't have a default value   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
>     ... 23 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're using Hibernate annotations, you don't need to use Hibernate XML mapping files.

Your error is probably because of your database schema. The Id_employeer column is not auto-increment.

Comment: Thank you for help, I solved this a 2 mins ago. 

I waste more than half ot the day, and solution was so easy ;O